# How to sort elements from objects from an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

So before I describe the problem here's a scenario.  I've created two classes a City that implements comparable and AncientCity that is a subclass of City.

City has an implemented compareTo method which compares the City's population and returns a certain integer as a result.

Same goes with AncientyCity, but it compares to the age of AncientCity.

I've created a Utilities class and implemented two generic methods sort & printAll.

For sort, I have to compare the elements of either City or AncientCity(we don't know depending what we claim in the main method) and if the first element happens to be larger than the second element, then it swaps the second to the first and first to second.

This is where the problem begins, I can't get sort method to arrange the elements in ascending order; I've tried using bubble sort but I couldn't get the elements to swap.

Is there any other way I can sort them in ascending order?

BTW you can't use Collections.sort(), that would defeat the purpose of my assignment.

Here's a snippet of the sort method (bear in mind I was using the String class for testing purposes before proceeding to compare City and/or AncientCity objects):

```
public static void sort(ArrayList<String> object){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 1; j < object.size(); j++ ){
                String a = object.get(i);
                String b = object.get(j);
                String tmp = null;
                if(a.compareTo(b) == 1){
                    tmp= b;
                    b = a;
                    a = tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't swap the values by swapping the object references locally in your method. I also suggest you program to the `List` interface. And I would recommend `> 0` instead of `== 1`. You need to initialize `j` to `i+1` and I would get the length once. Something like,

```
public static void sort(List<String> object) {
    int length = (object != null) ? object.size() : 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            String a = object.get(i);
            String b = object.get(j);
            if (a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
                object.set(j, a);
                object.set(i, b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```